# How to create a remove button to remove one div at a time using JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <div class= "button">
  <button id="More" type="submit">Add more Parameters</button>
  <button id="Remove" type="submit">Remove Parameters</button>
  </div>

  <script>
  var count = 2;
  $('#More').click(function(){
    if (count==11) {
       }
    else {
          $("div2").append("<div class='fieldBlock'><fieldset><legend>Parameter " + count + "</legend><label >Parameter Name: </label><select  type=text id='name" + count + "'  name='name' ><option></option></select></br></br><label >Address: </label><select  type=text id='address" + count + "'  name='address' ><option></option></select></br></br><label  >Data Size: </label> </br><select  type=text id='size" + count + "'  name='size' ><option></option></select>  </select> </br> </br><label >Write Data: </label> </br><input  type=text id='data" + count + "'  name='data' style='width: 14em;'></br> </br></fieldset></div>");
      count++;
      }
   });

  $('#Remove').click(function(){
      ....
    });
```

Can someone show me how if a user clicks on a remove button, the div that was appended can be removed? Also if user appends multiple times, I want the remove button to only remove one div at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not a tutorial site, or code writing service. Please ask a question **about something you have tried**.

Comment: @jay An html tag `div2`does not exists in each version of html specification. Another one: I think you have a missunderstanding of use `.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the id of Remove button to class, you may add the remove button to each new created div:

```js
$(function () {
  var count = 2;
  $('#More').on('click', function(){
    if (count==11) {

    }
    else {
      $(".div2").append("<div class='fieldBlock'><fieldset><legend>Parameter " + count + "</legend><label >Parameter Name: </label><select  type=text id='name" + count + "'  name='name' ><option></option></select></br></br><label >Address: </label><select  type=text id='address" + count + "'  name='address' ><option></option></select></br></br><label  >Data Size: </label> </br><select  type=text id='size" + count + "'  name='size' ><option></option></select>  </select> </br> </br><label >Write Data: </label> </br><input  type=text id='data" + count + "'  name='data' style='width: 14em;'></br> </br><button class=\"Remove\" type=\"submit\">Remove Parameters</button></fieldset></div>");
      count++;
    }
  });

  $('#Last').on('click', function(){
    $('div.fieldBlock:last').remove();
    count--;
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.Remove', function(e){
    $(this).closest('div.fieldBlock').remove();
    count--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="div2">
    <div class= "button">
        <button id="More" type="submit">Add more Parameters</button>
    </div>
    <div class= "button">
        <button id="Last" type="submit">Remove last Parameters</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to only remove the last box, right now in your code, they can remove parameter 2 before they remove parameter 3. Is there a way that they have to remove parameter 3 before they remove parameter 2?

Comment: If the user click on parameter 3 only this will be removed and after you can click on parameter 2 and so remove only that. To remove only the last div you need to select it using the :last selector.

Comment: @jay Snippet updated. Now I added a new button to remove only the last parameter

Answer (score 1):

This code will remove the last appended div only.
I've created div with id (div2) where all the divs will be appended.

```js
var count = 2;
  $('#More').click(function(){
    if (count==11) {
       }
    else {
          $("#div2").append("<div class='fieldBlock'><fieldset><legend>Parameter " + count + "</legend><label >Parameter Name: </label><select  type=text id='name" + count + "'  name='name' ><option></option></select></br></br><label >Address: </label><select  type=text id='address" + count + "'  name='address' ><option></option></select></br></br><label  >Data Size: </label> </br><select  type=text id='size" + count + "'  name='size' ><option></option></select>  </select> </br> </br><label >Write Data: </label> </br><input  type=text id='data" + count + "'  name='data' style='width: 14em;'></br> </br></fieldset></div>");
      count++;
      }
   });

  $('#Remove').click(function(){
        $('#div2').find('div').last().remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "button">
  <button id="More" type="submit">Add more Parameters</button>
  <button id="Remove" type="submit">Remove Parameters</button>
  </div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click','div',function(){
    $('div').removeAttr('current'); //removes attr from all divs
    $(this).attr('current','true'); // adds attr to div clicked
 })     

 $('body').on('click','#remove',function(){
    $('current="true"').remove();//removes div with attr current='true'
  })
});
```

I used the .on method to delegate the events since you are dynamically adding them.